# Which logical operations can I use to ignore irrelevant bits when masking?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, boolean-logic, bitmask, boolean-operations

### Context

Let's say that I have a system model which comprises of 8 Boolean variables. Together, they comprise a byte that may expresses the 128 state permutations of my system. Let this byte be `stateByte`, whereby each bit is one of my variables.

Now, suppose I have some enumerable states, such as:

```csharp
public enum States
{
    READY     = 0b_0000_0001
    OPERATING = 0b_0100_0000
    FAULT     = 0b_1000_0000
}
```

If it were that each of the `States` were discrete, I could easily determine `States currentState = (States)stateByte`, however my problem is:

My states are only each dependent on a subset of specific bits, not the entire byte. Specifically, there are some bits that are irrelevant depending on the state. To use pseudo notation, I  have the scenario below where `x` notates an irrelevant bit:

```csharp
public enum States
{
    READY     = 0b_0000_0001 // Exactly this permutation
    OPERATING = 0b_0100_0000 // Exactly this permutation
    FAULT     = 0b_1xxx_xxxx // Only bit 7 need be high to determine a fault
}
```

### Question

How can I use logical, bitwise operators (masking) in order to enumerate states from only relevant bits?

### Further Context

For those sticklers for detail who would question why I am trying to do this or why I cannot simply use thresholds, please see below the full state table of the hardware I am integrating:

[image]

Comment: [Logical AND operator &](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-and-operator-)

Comment: Question is tagged C#, so here is the flags attribute that is standard https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=net-5.0

Comment: @ThomasKoelle At first glance I think this may be exactly what I need. I’ve never encountered them before, thank you! If you had time to provide a full answer with example I’d be grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the binary and operator `&` to mask values, such as to only include certain bits:

```
0b_1xxx_xxxx & 0b_1000_0000 = 0b_1000_0000
0b_1xxx_xxxx & (1 << 7)     = 0b_1000_0000
0b_1xxx_xxxx & States.Fault = 0b_1000_0000
```

If you want to access certain bits often you could write an extension method like this:

```cs
public static boolean GetBit(this byte bitmask, int index) =>
    ((bitmask >> index) & 1) != 0;

0b_1xxx_xxxx.GetBit(7) = true
```

If you want to check multiple bits at once, you can use a pattern that matches all bits you want to check and compare them with another pattern containing all "correct" bits and 0s everywhere else:

```cs
   0b_x0xx_1000
 & 0b_0100_1111  // Only look at bits 0-3 and 6
== 0b_0000_1000  // Check that bit 6 is 0, 3 is 1 and 0-2 are 0
                 // Other bits are 0 due to the logical and
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your input! It would be as simple as that if it wasn’t for the specifically low (0) bits. For example Bit 7 must be high, Bit 6 must be low, and none of the others matter. I’m sure there’s some trick with the complement that I’m missing. I’m trying to avoid checking bit by bit...

Comment: What about doing `0b_1xxx_xxxx & 0b_1100_0000 == 0b_1000_0000`?

Comment: I think you’re still missing the crux of the issue, my friend. The table I included is perhaps a better example than the one I a wrote. Look at the fault state, where Bits 0-2 == 0, Bit 3 == 1, Bit 6 == 0 and all other are irrelevant. The operation we need must produce the same value regardless of the irrelevant bit values, AND won’t do it alone.

Comment: This seems to be solvable like in my previous comment: `x & 0b_0100_1111 == 0b_0000_1000`

Comment: Right!!! Okay, I’ve caught up now. Sorry, I’d misunderstood from you initial answer. According to your method then, I’d have a corresponding Mask to each State, applied prior with & in order to “forcibly pull down” the irrelevant bits. That should work! If you’d kindly clarify your answer a bit, I’ll mark it as answered. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If the flags solution is valid then it would be done like this:

```
    [Flags]
    public enum States
    {
        READY = 0b_0000_0001,
        OPERATING = 0b_0100_0000,
        FAULT = 0b_1000_0000
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = (States)5;
        var check = s = States.FAULT | States.OPERATING;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by one of the other answers to this question, I created the following extension method:

```cs
public static class ByteExtensions
{
    public static bool MatchesBitPattern(this byte value, string pattern)
    {
        if (pattern == null || !Regex.IsMatch(pattern, "^[01X]{8}$"))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Value must be an 8-character string containing only the characters 0, 1 or X.", nameof(pattern));
        }

        byte mask = Convert.ToByte(pattern.Replace('0', '1').Replace('X', '0'), 2);
        byte result = Convert.ToByte(pattern.Replace('X', '0'), 2);
        return (value & mask) == result;
    }
}
```

which you would use something like this:

```cs
internal class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = "0XX1XX00";
        byte b;
        b =            0b_11010100;
        Console.WriteLine(b.MatchesBitPattern(pattern));  // false
        b =            0b_01010100;
        Console.WriteLine(b.MatchesBitPattern(pattern));  // true
    }
}
```